# ReactNative: App runs on device can't respond to click event

Tags: react-native

I develop the app with React-Native, and it is running very well in ios **simulator**, but when I run it on **device** it responds to my **click event very very slow**. But the scrollview is OK. 
Anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

PS:React-Native version:0.34.0

PSS: I found out that this happens when I run app from the xcode project. And the xcode log console keeps printing many logs.

PSSS: The RAM keeps up growing!!!!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I find that the RAM keep upgrowing!!!! Why???

Answer (score 0):

A ios simulator have a slow mode. Try cmd+t for desactivate/activate slow mode.

Comment: I am confused for it runs ok days ago, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that is caused by package "react-native-logger". I uninstall it and the app runs normally so far.